# Burn CD from CD - Exact Duplicate

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I have a Windows XP 64bit disc that I would like to copy on my Windows XP machine  so that if I ever broke/misplaced the disc I still have a copy to use my key with.

As I do not have a ISO file (also I believe Microsoft will be removing theirs soon too) what is the best way to do this.

Inserting the original disc and dragging/dropping the files to a folder then burning to another disc does not sound too good.

Comment: Dragging and dropping files would not be enough anyway. There is other "invisible" (not as a file at least) data that needs to be there. If you want to understand better, google for mbr/bootloader/livecd

Comment: @miniBill didnt think it would be, is there not a program/command similar to **dd** in linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use a program such as [Power ISO](http://www.poweriso.com) which effectively enables you to make an ISO file that is an exact replica of the disc you wish to copy and then burn a duplicate physical copy afterwards. Take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.poweriso.com/tutorials/copy-disc.htm)

Comment: imgBurn is a better solution, Its free open source, POWERISO can only create a image of 300mb or less, otherwise you must pay. I voted your answer as Correct as it provided me the info.

Comment: You can also create ISO from cd using infra recorder which is also free.

Comment: Ashampoo Burning Studio 6 - Free Edition can also be used to make ISOs, and burn them. https://www.ashampoo.com/en/usd/pin/0710/Offline/Ashampoo-Burning-Studio-6 . As someone who owns PowerISO I will say it's worth the money if you ever need a good ISO editor/creator/burner